# Detect execution flow divergence

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have an application that should produce the same output given the same input but it produces different outputs across executions.

Is it possible to use GDB to detect divergence between executions? Is it at all possible to automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use GDB to detect divergence between executions?

If the application is single-threaded, [reverse debugging](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/news/reversible.html) can help. See [this article](http://blog.jwhitham.org/2015/05/review-undodb-reversible-debugger.html) for an example using UndoDB.

You should also make sure there are no uninitialized memory reads, using either Valgrind or [MemorySantizer](https://code.google.com/p/memory-sanitizer/wiki/MemorySanitizer).

If the application is multi-threaded, reverse debugging is unlikely to help, but data race detectors like [ThreadSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/data-race-test/wiki/ThreadSanitizer) may.

> Is it at all possible to automate this?

You can (and should) certainly run {Address,Memory,Thread}Sanitizer's regularly over your test suite (you *do* have a test suite, right?).

With reverse debugging, not much further automation should be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing system calls that could return different results based on the system state, chances are there's undefined behavior somewhere in your program.

There's not much you can do with GDB besides run your application step by step to find the problem. I recommend you [UndoDB](http://undo-software.com/) for your case, it's a nice debugger with reversible execution function.

As @Employed Russian pointed out, you should run some tool to test uninitialized memory, which is one of the most common causes of undefined behavior.